# Issue running a react web application and fixing the errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications, npm

I'm trying to run a react web application I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/marshallmurphy/Web-Apps/tree/master/Medication%20Reminder%20React%20App). I'm running this code by typing "npm start" in the terminal and then going to  http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/. However the application doesn't move past the first screen after clicking "Get Started". [image]

After inspecting the page I see the following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...and you check this [also](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm)

you must add check package.json and delete "test" "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" inside "scripts" object.

Let's add the start command instead.

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
```

And also check your `node_moduls` folder, and also you must do `npm install`

Comment: I have npm installed. "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot" worked but I'm still receiving the same errors. Did the web application work on your computer?

Comment: Okay so we know the code works. It must be something to do with the versions of npm or node I'm running. I did npm install so everything I need should be installed. What did you want me to check inside the node_moduls folder?

Comment: No @DanteGreyson i thing code have something missing..you just check another project...i mean GitHub Battle React App....it is perfectly working... just do npm install and npm start

Comment: Yeah I agree. It's the code. Do you think the error is due to the fact that the Medication Reminder app is using React (ES5) ?

Comment: just see README.md file and note line number 49...the Medication Reminder app is using React (ES6+)

Comment: Actually he's saying that he's going to write the app in ES6 in the future. But this particular app is written in ES5 right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129596/discussion-between-dante-greyson-and-karthick-nagarajan).